# How to get All data in CurrentState in React js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how to get single data from state ? basically I want to post the data in firestore but i cant get that how to get all data from specific index of array ?

```
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
    
    //this contain all the data but how to get single data from state?
    console.log("postData", tableData);

    //just like this

    console.log("date" , tableData.date);          //undefined
    console.log("date" , tableData.description);   //undefined
    console.log("date" , tableData.cashAdd);       //undefined
    
    //also I do with find function but there is an another way to do it ?
    
    const dataa = tableData.find((x)=> {
            return x;
           })
    console.log("date", dataa.date);   
//only get 1 date of a single array not an all the dates of all arrays
```

Comment: does `tableData[0].date` do the trick? `TableData` is an array, you need to select which object to access before being able to read its properties

Comment: `tableData.find` will return the first element where the given condition is met (in your case `x`), so the return value is an object and not the array anymore

Comment: but how to get all dates ?  tableData[0].date only get date of index 0 and how to get all indexes of dates ?

Comment: either iterate over your array with a for-loop and do some calculations or whatever, or if you want just want to get all dates in a new array, you could use something like `tableData.map(data => data.date)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter out that particular data based on id from main data array.

**Example:**

```js
const { useState } = React;
 
const data = [{
  id:1,
  name: 'Dan',
  description:'Dab',
  date: 'someDate',
  cashAdd: true
},{
  id:2,
  name: 'John',
  description:'John',
  date: 'someDate',
  cashAdd: false
},{
  id:3,
  name: 'Riya',
  description:'Riya',
  date: 'someDate',
  cashAdd: true
}]

function App() {
 const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

 const selectedItem = data.find(item => item.id === selectedId)
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => {
          return <li onClick={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}>{item.name}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
      <h2>Selected Item</h2>
      {JSON.stringify(selectedItem)}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```